# How to prove $2^{2^{6n+2}} + 21$ is a composite number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, perfect-powers

How to prove that $$ 2^{2^{6n+2}} + 21 $$ is a composite number for each $$n=1,2,3,\ldots$$

I'm stuck on a what seems like a simple problem but I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Try reducing modulo some small primes.

Comment: no, the smalest prime divisor for the case $n=1$ is 37.

Comment: No to what? And that seems like a good start to me.

Comment: @Leox I think 37 does not divide F(1)

Comment: @peter.petrov I think it does;
$$2^{2^{6\times1+2}}+21=37×439×53113×98893×100213×7469213659×1813206700101770737586682395155622856503930399533.$$

Comment: Oh, it's 6n+2, not 6n+1. OK.

Answer (score 1):

Let's denote the number by $F(n)$, for $n=0,1,2,...$
One can prove by induction that $37$ divides $F(n)$ for all $n$.
This is easy to see if one uses Fermat's little theorem.
I have certain problems with MathJax so I cannot write the full proof here.

**EDIT:**

1) For $n=0$, we have $F(0) = 37$ which is divisible by 37.
2) For $F(n)$ we assume that $37$ divides $F(n)$.
3) Now for $F(n+1)$ we have:
$F(n+1) = 2^{2^{6n+8}} + 21 = {(2^{2^{6n+2}})}^{2^6} + 21 = (mod\ 37) = 16^{2^6} + 21 = 16^{64} + 21 = 2^{256} + 21 = 2^{(36.7)}.2^4 + 21 = {2^{36}}^7.2^4 + 21 = 1^7.16 + 21 = 37 = 0\ (mod \ 37)$

Comment: However it would fit in a little margin?

Comment: @SimonS I am just not so good with MathJax and my resolution is small. I didn't quite mean what you're referring to even though I guessed it would be interpreted that way :)

Comment: The crucial third step seems to be lacking some details... could you expand please?

Comment: @OK, trying one last time.

Comment: @Servaes OK, it's done now.

Comment: I don't see how you get
$$\left(2^{2^{6n+2}}\right)^{2^6}+21\equiv 16^{2^6}+21\pmod{37},$$
I think it requires an argument?

Comment: @Servaes: that comes from the inductive hypothesis. By assuming $2^{2^{6n+2}}+21\equiv 0\pmod{7}$, it follows that $2^{2^{6n+2}}\equiv -16\pmod{37}$.

Comment: @Jack Thanks, that clarifies it for me, modulo some typo's ;)

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio I assume 7 is a typo? It should be 37. Otherwise nice.

Comment: @ostochast: sure, the first line should have been $2^{2^{6n+2}}+21\equiv 0\pmod{37}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Just a small note: it is $16$ as I wrote, and not $-16$.

Comment: @peter.petrov: you are right, but that does not matter so much, since we square it.

Answer (score 0):

$ 2^{2^{6n+2}} + 21=2^{4 (2^{6n} )}-2^4+2^4+21= $

$ =37+2^4\left (2^{4(2^{6n}-1 )}-1 \right )=37+2^4\left (2^{4(2^6-1 )(2^{6(n-1)}+ \dots +1 )}-1 \right )=$

$ =37+2^4\left (2^{36 \cdot 7 \cdot (2^{6(n-1)}+ \dots +1 )}-1 \right )=$

$ =37+2^4\left (2^{36}-1\right )\left (\dots   \right ) \equiv 0 \bmod 37$

Comment: Um.... five years too late.  And not significantly different that peter.petrov.  Although admittedly I like yours better than peter.petrov's.   But.... five years too late.

Comment: @fleablood I replied because it was activated today